# How I can filter a array by another array with EmberJs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm new with emberjs.

I've two arrays in filterActivities function

```
filterActivities: (->
activities = @get('activities')     //get ['farmer', 'rancher']
producers = @get('producerTypes')   //get [code: 'farmer', name: 'agriculutor', etc...]

filtering = producers.filter(producers) =>
  activities.contains(producers.get('code')) 
).property('producerTypes.@each')
```

how I can filter producers by activities using the method filter of ember.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I let you translate back to coffee :

```
var filtering = producers.filter(function(producer){
    return activities.contains(producer.get('code'));
});
```

in short, `filters` return an array which contains "each" element of another array who returns `true` to the callback function.